# Prevent Observabe.error complete and dispose swift

Tags: swift, rx-swift, moya

I have an observable (request from network) and dont want it to be disposed when I got an error

My custom error

```
   enum MyError: Error {
        case notFound
        case unknown
    }
```

My network request using Moya

```
let registerRequest = didTapJoinButton.withLatestFrom(text.asObservable())
            .flatMapLatest { text in
                provider.rx.request(API.register(text: text))
            }
            .flatMapLatest({ (response) -> Observable<Response> in
                let statusCode = response.statusCode

                if statusCode.isSuccessStatus() {
                    return Observable.just(response)

                } else if statusCode.isNotFoundStatus() {
                    return Observable.error(MyError.notFound)

                } else {
                    return Observable.error(MyError.unknown)
                }
            })
            .materialize()
            .share(replay: 1)
```

Looks great. I use materialize() to prevent observable being disposed on error

Subscribe: (If status code 200)
Everything works just fine, I got response and the stream is not disposed

```
   registerEventRequest.subscribe(onNext: { (next) in
            print("NEXT: \(next)")
        }, onError: { (error) in
            print("ERRRRROR ME: \(error)")
        }, onCompleted: {
            print("Completed")
        }) {
            print("Disposed")
        }
```

BUT if status code is something like 404. I got the error as I expected. However, hey look at the console log

```
NEXT: error(notFound)
Completed
Disposed
```

It jumps to NEXT which I expected. But why it throw complete and dispose my sequence.

My question is Why did it dispose my sequence and how I can prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.materialize()` does not *prevent* an observable from being disposed on error. When an Observable emits an error, it is finished and materialize merely converts that error into a next event.

You need to put the materialize *inside* the first flatMapLatest to prevent the error from escaping the flatMap closure.

This video might help (note `selectMany` is the same as `flatMap`) https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/J.Van.Gogh/Reactive-Extensions-API-in-depth-SelectMany?term=select%20many&lang-en=true

---

Here's another way to compose the Observable:

```
let registerRequest = didTapJoinButton.withLatestFrom(text.asObservable())
    .flatMapLatest { text in
        provider.rx.request(API.register(text: text))
            .materialize()
    }
    .map { (event) -> Event<Response> in
        switch event {
        case .next(let response) where response.statusCode.isNotFoundStatus():
            return Event.error(MyError.notFound)

        case .next(let response) where response.statusCode.isSuccessStatus() == false:
            return Event.error(MyError.unknown)

        default:
            return event
        }
    }
    .share(replay: 1)
```

I moved `materialize()` where it belongs so errors won't break the chain. I also swapped out the second `flatMapLatest` for a simple `map` since the extra work wasn't necessary.

The switch statement could have also been written like this:

```
switch event {
case .next(let response):
    let statusCode = response.statusCode
    if statusCode.isNotFoundStatus() {
        return Event.error(MyError.notFound)
    }
    else if statusCode.isSuccessStatus() {
        return event
    }
    else {
        return Event.error(MyError.unknown)
    }

default:
    return event
}
```

But I think the way I did it is cleaner because it reduces the cyclomatic complexity of the closure.

---

Here is code to deal with the concern brought up in the comments:

```
extension ObservableType {
    func flatMapLatestT<T, U>(_ selector: @escaping (T) -> Observable<U>) -> Observable<Event<U>>
        where Self.E == Event<T>
    {
        return self.flatMapLatest { (event) -> Observable<Event<U>> in
            switch event {
            case .next(let element):
                return selector(element).materialize()
            case .completed:
                return .just(Event<U>.completed)
            case .error(let error):
                return .just(Event<U>.error(error))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gist contains a whole suite of operators for dealing with Events. https://gist.github.com/dtartaglia/d7b8d5c63cf0c91b85b629a419b98d7e

Comment: True. I have just realised that. But if we put materialize into the first flatMapLatest, it might be difficult for me to handle the data status code. Could you give me an example (show me the code) how to do it correctly

Comment: I added to my answer.

Comment: Do you normally handle error like this. I am practicing to use MVVM

Comment: I don't normally use Moya but yes, what you have seems fine to me. You should probably wrap it up into a ObservableType extension function so you can reuse the code for other types of requests.

Comment: Have learned so much from you. You are brilliant :) Thank. It is true that I should wrap it up somehow so I will try to learn about ObservableType later, have no idea about it yet

Comment: But the way we materialize it might cause problem when we decide to chain request right? Like request1- > flatMap -> request2... We have to dematerialize each time we chain request

Comment: You don't want to `dematerialize()` because that would break the chain. You can use the `flatMapLatestT` operator that I added to the answer. That code also shows how to make your own operator or as I called it earlier an ObservableType extension function.

Comment: Could you also add example use that extension to wrap the code (refactor our old code with extension) and also one example where we can chain the request. Btw thank for RxEarthquake, inspiring project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185881/discussion-between-coinhndp-and-daniel-t).

Comment: "You need to put the materialize inside the first flatMapLatest to prevent the error from escaping the flatMap closure." that was the key of success for me , many thanks